# MYSQL - insert a variable into a string

Tags: mysql

I have created 2 variables

```
SET @SG_Positivity = 1600000000000027;
SET @SG_Relationship = 1700000000000027;
```

I want to use these inside of a string in my INSERT

```
INSERT INTO `core`.`card_config` (`version`,`scoring_model_id`,`locale_id`,`card_type`,`config`,`company_interview_id`)
VALUES('1',@ScoreModelID,'1','TTC','{"'+@SG_Positivity+'":{"summary":Tailored, personalized care"'+@SG_Relationship+'":{"summary":Ability to move others to action',NULL);
```

When executing the statement, I get the following error

> Warning Code : 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '{"'

Comment: use **CONCAT(...)** to add the elements. + dosent work in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO `core`.`card_config` (`version`,`scoring_model_id`,`locale_id`,`card_type`,`config`,`company_interview_id`)
VALUES('1',@ScoreModelID,'1','TTC','{""'+@SG_Positivity+'''":{"''summary":Tailored, personalized care"'+@SG_Relationship+'":{"summary":Ability to move others to action"',
NULL);

Try above solution if nothing work then refer [refer this for more information](https://chartio.com/learn/sql-tips/single-double-quote-and-backticks-in-mysql-queries/)